# UWP app certification kit crashes during testing

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-store

This is not a coding problem but I had to ask it with the community. My uwp app was being rejected by **certification** process of the store (due to crash and hangs, which I can't reproduce on my machine) so I thought I should try and analyze it with the app certification kit on my own machine (which I was doing before with 16199 certification kit).

But now with release of latest app certification kit (**17134.12**) I have the latest one now and when I try to run the certification kit on it, the wizard just crashes after testing first three steps. If there is a problem with the app, the kit should tell me that in the end result after going through all tests, but it just randomly crashes during testing which was weird to me as it never happened before on any previous certification kits. The kit crashes on validation on any package, I have tested with multiple apps.

Comment: I have some questions to ask you. 1) What's you OS version? 2) What's your project's target version? 3) What's your visual studio version? 4) What's the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` version?

Comment: Then, let's also do some troubleshootings: If you just create a new blank  project and a page with just a button click function, after that, you create app package and use  app certification kit 17134.12 to validute it. Please check if you still face this issue.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I am facing the same issue when creating appxbundle of UWP app for all platforms (x86, x64, ARM). The kit just closes after 3rd step. No error message. It is the same when creating the x64 package only. When creating for x86 only, all tests run through, but the kit crashes at the end at 2nd step of report creation. Error dialog appears, saying: "Error in generating report. The app will be closed." (translated from german).

Comment: When creating ARM package only, all tests (except "deploy- and launch tests" and "check of supported directory structure", because not selectable) pass and the report is created successfully.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT 1) Windows 10 Pro 1803 64 bit. 2) Target version: 14393. Min- version: 10240. 3) Community 2017 15.7.3. 4) 5.0.0

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adad5f55-776a-45f4-9b9f-c32fbacb94a1/windows-app-certification-kit-1001713412-fails?forum=wpsubmit

Comment: Run it in command line mode to get error:  appcert.exe reset
    appcert.exe test -appxpackagepath "path to .appxbundle" -reportoutputpath c:\temp\report.xml